# Tomcat REALM doesn't authenticate in some cases

Tags: tomcat, authentication, tomcat7, jdbcrealm

I am using Tomcat 7 and Realm for authenticating using JDBC. I extended DataSourceRealm to use our own implementation. My problem is that in some cases it seems like Tomcat REALM doesn't call any methods in the DataSourceRealm but fails the authentication from the beginning. This happens usually when changing a password in the DB while the user is authenticated. After invalidating the user and trying to login again tomcat doesn't let me in no matter what password I try using. Only restarting tomcat will fix this.

Putting breakpoint in the DataSourceRealm class (the extended one) I see that normally tomcat will call the authenticate method but in the special case TC simply doesn't call anything in the DataSourceRealm. Why is this? Is there some kind of caching? There is nothing documented about this.

And one more thing: many times changing the user name character to upper case will work. So I can login as aDmin but not as admin (with aDmin it will call the DataSourceRealm as expected) which makes me convinced that the users are somehow cached.

Comment: Please check the `catalina` file. I think an exception had been occurred. After that let me know the exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having this problem with Basic Authentication, it's the **browser** which caches the credentials and tries to use them again.

If you authenticate once, change the credentials, log off and try to log in again, the browser will not ask the credentials again and will fail to pass.

Try closing the browser and opening the page again, it should ask the login and password again.